# How to solve the "bad window path name ".!labelframe.!canvas.!frame" error in tkinter python?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

This is my code:

```
mycanvas = Canvas(self.search_result_frame)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT)

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.search_result_frame, orient="vertical", command=mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
mycanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion = mycanvas.bbox('all')))

        self.sample_frame = Frame(mycanvas)
        mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.sample_frame, anchor=E)
        for widget in self.search_result_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        if len(matching_bills) > 0: 
            for bill in matching_bills:
                with open(f'{self.bill_folder}//{bill}//data//bill_details.json', 'r') as bill_json_file:
                    bill_details = json.loads(bill_json_file.read())

                    customer_name = bill_details["customer_details"][0]
                    payment_method = bill_details["payment_method"]
                    date_of_issue = bill_details["date_of_issue"]
                    date_of_issue = datetime.strptime(date_of_issue, "%d/%m/%Y")
                    date_of_issue = date_of_issue.strftime("%d %b %Y")

                    # # -------------------- Search Result Frame Contents
                    result_frame = Frame(self.sample_frame, bg=self.bg3, bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
                    result_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=2)

                    result_billno_lbl = Label(result_frame, text=bill, bg=self.bg1, fg="#FFF", font=self.search_results_font1, padx=22, pady=3)
                    result_billno_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=8, sticky=W)

                    billed_to_lbl = Label(result_frame, text=f"Billed To - {customer_name}", bg=self.bg1, fg="#FFF", font=self.search_results_font2, bd=2, relief=RAISED, padx=12, pady=3)
                    billed_to_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=80, sticky=W)

                    billed_type_lbl = Label(result_frame, text=f"Bill Type - {payment_method}", bg=self.bg1, fg="#FFF", font=self.search_results_font2, bd=2, relief=RAISED, padx=12, pady=3)
                    billed_type_lbl.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

                    issued_on_lbl = Label(result_frame, text=f"Issued On - {date_of_issue}", bg=self.bg1, fg="#FFF",
                    font=self.search_results_font2, bd=2, relief=RAISED, padx=12, pady=3)
                    issued_on_lbl.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=80, sticky=W)

                    view_btn = Button(result_frame, text="View", font="Comicsan 14", bd=2, relief=GROOVE, bg="#000", fg="#FFF", padx=1, command=lambda bill=bill: self.view_bill(bill))
                    view_btn.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        elif len(matching_bills) == 0:
            for widgets in self.search_result_frame.winfo_children():
                        widgets.destroy()

            no_result_lbl = Label(self.search_result_frame, text=f"No search result found for {bill_cat}", font=self.search_results_font1, bg=self.bg3, fg="#FFF")
            no_result_lbl.pack(fill=X)
```

When I run it, it shows me the `bad window path name ".!labelframe.!canvas.!frame` error and when I try to do the same thing without object-oriented in tkinter then it works well !

Comment: `tkinter` is telling you that you destroyed the frame/canvas and then you tried accessing it. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: You have destroyed everything inside `self.search_result_frame` before the line `if len(matching_bills) > 0`,  so the canvas and its children are all destroyed.

Comment: They their, Thanks Very Much !!! You were right ! I was destroying all the label frame widgets and by removing it, the program works